# min operator over meshgrid

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to use something like [the slice command](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/slice.html) as described in [Exploring Volumes with Slice Planes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/exploring-volumes-with-slice-planes.html#bqrm8bh), but the function I want to visualize is the following scalar field:

f(x,y,z)=min(1.x,2.y,3.z)

I do:

```
[x,y,z]=meshgrid(0:10,0:10,0:10);
```

I'm not sure if it is correct, but I tried:

```
v=min([x.*1,y.*2,z.*3]);
```

The problem is (I don't know why) this produces an 1x33x11 array, which logically causes an error when running slice (since v needs to be the same size as x, y and z, which are 11x11x11).

How can I generate v as needed for slice ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in this part of the code:

```
[x.*1,y.*2,z.*3]
```

Here you are just appending your three matrices resulting in a [11 33 11] matrix, instead you want to stack them to a [11 11 11 3] matrix. To do so use `cat` to have your three 3D-Matrices stacked among the fourth dimension.

```
v=min(cat(4,x.*1,y.*2,z.*3),[],4);
```